# How does one sort using Entity Framework Dynamic "SortBy" string on a complex object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, sorting

I am writing an entity framework query that maps to a complex object of objects. I am using jquery datatables which passes over the query sort dynamically as a string typical like "item_id" or "item_id DESC". When passed into a SoryBy clause, it sorts the database results be the item id column. This is fine if that is the base object, but if I have a wrapper object which contains the object, it says item id is not defined for type ItemInfo.

A mockup of the classes are as follows.

```
public class Item {
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
}

public class ItemCategory {
        public String category { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
    }

public class ItemInfo {
        public Item item { get; set; }
        public ItemCategory category { get; set; }
    }
```

What does the string for the .SortBy clause need to be to get the item_id from Item in an ItemInfo query?

```
IQueryable<ItemInfo> query = (from i in Item
                              join c in ItemCategory on i.category_id equals c.category_id
                              select new ItemInfo() {
                                 item = i,
                                 category = c
                              };
```

Comment: select `ItemId=i.item_id` then pass it into order by clause like `order by i.item_id`

Comment: @BradleyUffner It looks like that code doesn't work on Entity Framework SQL Server. It looks like that is a pure c# solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Simpler scenario with pure Linq:

If your scenario is simpler and you don't need dynamic at all, you can just do like this:

```
query = query.OrderBy(i => i.item.item_id);
// OR
query = query.OrderByDescending(i => i.item.item_id);
```

..which would use the property itself.

---

### Dynamic scenario with "Dynamic Linq"

If you really needed dynamic (which means you would have to order by any fields and didn't want to put a lot of `if`s in your code), then you would need to install this package [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) by running this in the *Package Manager Console*:

```
Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic
```

Then you add this `using` clause:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

Then you can achieve dynamic ordering with the following:

```
query = query.OrderBy("item.item_id DESC"); // keep the IQueryable
// OR
var items = query.OrderBy("item.item_id DESC").ToList(); // order in database...
```

When using this dynamic library, there is no `OrderByDescending`, since you can pass **ASC** or **DESC** with the string passed to the `OrderBy()` method (as in my example).

Take note `item` is the same name of the property inside `ItemInfo`. Also, `ToList()` is just an example, actually you don't need it at all, depending on your scenario.

---

Although I'd suggest you to change your `ItemInfo` to be like this:

```
public class ItemInfo {
        public int item_id { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
    }
```

...then fix your query to populate accordingly:

```
IQueryable<ItemInfo> query = (from i in Item
                              join c in ItemCategory on i.category_id equals c.category_id
                              select new ItemInfo() {
                                 item_id = i.item_id,
                                 category_id = c.category_id
                              };

query.OrderBy("item_id DESC");
```

This looks **simpler and cleaner** in my point of view. I'd avoid to put the whole object inside `ItemInfo`, keeping there exactly the properties you need, so you wouldn't load all the fields unnecessarily from database every time.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Does the order by do desc if it's passed in as a string? I saw an orderbydescending and I'm not sure if that would need to be used over orderby. 2. My order by doesn't except a string parameter. Is there a using statement I need to add to get that? I get: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 When I saw you mentioning *dynamic* I thought you were already using `System.Linq.Dynamic;`. I'm edited my answer.

Comment: If you also need ThenBy(), this is supported by https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core